# On page load - how to go to page anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an url like that ../page/5/product

This page have anchors to ../page/5/product/10#anchor01 , ../page/5/product/8#anchor01 etc.

How is it possible to jump, after the page is loaded, to the anchor displayed on the new page.

Hope someone could give me a hint.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the value of `hash` of the `location` object will automagicly lead you to the anchor.

```
location.hash = "#anchor";
```

Comment: A bit faster than me so i dropped!

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.. could you give me a few more details?

Comment: have a look on the answer below - there I explain my situation..